# Tunnel a whole desktop over ssh to X11 running on OSX

Tags: ssh, macosx

My main workstation is OSX (as I spend a lot of time developing iOS and OSX software), however I use Ubuntu for a bunch of things.

I've got Ubuntu running on another machine, and would like to tunnel the desktop over ssh to OSX. I'm an 1000mbit ethernet.

It works for the following:

```
ssh -X user@server.mydomain
nautilus&   #Or firefox, etc - will open the window on my OSX Machine
```

However for a whole desktop:

```
gnome-session&
```

It gives the error message "We failed but the fail whale is dead". . . this has to be the most fantastic error message ever (although it doesn't help me very much in explaining what went wrong).

Comment: I think the most fantastic error message ever is "You don't exist, go away!", but that's a pretty good one too ;)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/621606/can-i-use-a-desktop-environment-with-x11-forwarding-through-ssh

Answer (score 4):

(Self answer: Still looking for a more complete answer)

I was not able to run gnome-session - I even tried Xephry and Xnest for this.

However, I was able to run:

```
gnome-panel&
```

. . and this gives me most of want I want. I now have the important parts of the Gnome desktop system - the graphical "Applications" menu, allowing me to find and launch apps, without having to know where they live on the disk.

*Update: This also works incredibly well over a meager wifi connection!*